# javafx - TableView Nested UI elements looses reference data object on dynamic addition of row

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to create an API, which can dynamically populate tableview with different Nested UI components in each cell of tableview. I'm able to bind the data set to Model object with the table.
The problem is when I try to dynamically add and try to enable the edit, the object reference is seems to messed up.
FYI:
[image]

As you see I've last column with 4 buttons, which is Add, Edit, Delete, Reset features. Once click on Add - it clones the current row, click on edit - it enable the `ComboBox` of Coulmn Category, click on delete - it deletes current row.

What I face is that upon adding multiple entries, I do get the row added dynamically, but then click on first row edit button - then multiple `ComboBox` is enabled, which is not intended use. The use case is current row's `ComboBox` must be only be enabled.

Implementation: I've written custom API which extends `TableView<S>`.
Following snippet may help:

```
//column category
    final ClumpElement< ConstraintsDataModel, String > categoryElement =
        new ClumpElement<>( ClumpType.COMBOBOX, true, getCategoryData() );
    categoryElement.setClumpTableCellValue( data -> data.categoryProperty() );
    categoryElement.setClumpTableNodeAction( ( control, data ) -> {
      final ComboBox< String > comboBox = (ComboBox< String >)control;
      comboBox.disableProperty().bind( data.disableProperty() );
    } );
    clumpTableView.addNewColumn( "Category", categoryElement );


    // column Action
    final ClumpElement< ConstraintsDataModel, String > buttonsElement =
        new ClumpElement<>( ClumpType.GROUP_BUTTONS, 4, "+", "✎", "X", "↻" );
    buttonsElement.setClumpTableNodeAction( ( control, data ) -> {
      final Button button = (Button)control;
      switch( button.getText() ) {
        case "+":
          final ConstraintsDataModel ref =
              clumpTableView.getItems().get( clumpTableView.getItems().size() - 1 );
          if( ConstraintsDataModel.isValidModel( ref ) )
            clumpTableView.getItems().add( new ConstraintsDataModel( data ) );
          else
            System.out.println( "ERROR: Finish previous constraints" );
          break;

        case "✎":
          data.setDisableValue( false );
          button.setText( "✔" );
          break;

        case "✔":
          data.setDisableValue( true );
          button.setText( "✎" );
          break;

    default:
          //NOTHING
          break;
      }
    } );
    clumpTableView.addNewColumn( "Action", buttonsElement );

    clumpTableView.setItems( getData() );
```

This is my `CustomTableView` class:

```
public < T > void addNewColumn( final String columnName, final ClumpElement< S, T > element ) {
    final TableColumn< S, T > column = new TableColumn<>( columnName );
    getColumns().add( column );
    if( element.getClumpTableCellValue() != null ) {
      column.setCellValueFactory( param -> element.getClumpTableCellValue()
                                                  .act( param.getValue() ) );
    }
    clumpCellCall( columnName, element, column );
  }

private < T > void clumpCellCall( final String colName, final ClumpElement< S, T > element,
      final TableColumn< S, T > column ) {
    switch( element.getUiNode() ) {
      case COMBOBOX:
        if( element.getItems() != null && !element.getItems().isEmpty() ) {
          column.setCellFactory( param -> {
            final ClumpComboBoxTableCell< S, T > clumpComboBoxTableCell =
                new ClumpComboBoxTableCell<>( element.isDisable(), element.getItems() );
            clumpComboBoxTableCell.prefWidthProperty().bind( column.widthProperty() );
            clumpComboBoxTableCell.selectionListener( element );
            return clumpComboBoxTableCell;
          } );
        }
        break;

  case GROUP_BUTTONS:
    column.setCellFactory( param -> {
      final ClumpButtonsTableCell< S, T > clumpButtonsTableCell =
          new ClumpButtonsTableCell<>( element.getNoOfElements() );
      clumpButtonsTableCell.prefWidthProperty().bind( column.widthProperty() );
      IntStream.range( 0, element.getNoOfElements() ).forEach( item -> {
        final Button button = clumpButtonsTableCell.getButtons().get( item );
        button.setText( element.getNames().get( item ) );
        button.setOnAction( event -> {
          if( element.getClumpTableNodeAction() != null
              && clumpButtonsTableCell.getIndex() < getItems().size() ) {
            element.getClumpTableNodeAction()
                   .act( button, getItems().get( clumpButtonsTableCell.getIndex() ) );
          }
        } );
      } );
      return clumpButtonsTableCell;
    } );
    break;

      default:
        column.setCellFactory( params -> {
          final TextFieldTableCell< S, T > textFieldTableCell = new TextFieldTableCell<>();
          textFieldTableCell.setConverter( new StringConverter< T >() {

            @Override
            public String toString( final T object ) {
              return (String)object;
            }

            @Override
            public T fromString( final String string ) {
              return (T)string;
            }
          } );
          return textFieldTableCell;
        } );
        break;
    }
  }
```

In my custom API, which shall invoke a custom `TableCell<S,T>` which has `ComboBox<T>` pretty standard implementation as per docs. Here its inside a selection listener, as I found that when the cell renders, only this selection listener is called.

```
public abstract class AbstractClumpTableCell< S, T > extends TableCell< S, T > {

  public AbstractClumpTableCell() {
    setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY );
    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  }

  public abstract void renewItem( T item );

  @Override
  protected void updateItem( T item, boolean empty ) {
    super.updateItem( item, empty );
    if( empty ) {
      setGraphic( null );
    } else {
      renewItem( item );
    }
  }
}

public class ClumpComboBoxTableCell< S, T > extends AbstractClumpTableCell< S, T > {


  private final ComboBox< T > comboBox;


  @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
  public ClumpComboBoxTableCell( final boolean isDisable, final ObservableList< T > item ) {
    super();
    this.comboBox = new ComboBox<>( item );
    this.comboBox.setDisable( isDisable );
    this.comboBox.valueProperty().addListener( ( obs, oVal, nVal ) -> {
      ObservableValue< T > property = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue( getIndex() );
      if( property instanceof WritableValue ) {
        ((WritableValue< T >)property).setValue( nVal );
      }
    } );
  }

  @Override
  public void renewItem( T item ) {
    comboBox.setValue( item );
    setGraphic( comboBox );
  }

  public ComboBox< T > getComboBox() {
    return comboBox;
  }

  protected void selectionListener( final ClumpElement< S, T > element ) {
    this.comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( ( obs, oVal, nVal ) -> {
      if( element.getClumpTableNodeAction() != null
          && getIndex() < getTableView().getItems().size() ) {
        element.getClumpTableNodeAction().act( this.comboBox,
                                               getTableView().getItems().get( getIndex() ) );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

And my Data Model has a `SimpleStringProperty` that is binded to the column accordingly.

So, How can I bind the Nested UI elements correctly rowise within the `TableView<S>`? Is my approach right or is there alternatives?

Comment: Are you sure you use different TableCell instances for each cell? My problem sounds like you have a common instance in the column. That's why you get odd behavior in the other cells.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Yes, I've new object created for every instance. What I'm not sure is that when calling, within `update(T item)` is it taking the same UI component?

Comment: @mrmcwolf The `ClumpElement` Object is a custom one, which shall create a new Objects of `CustomComboBoxTableCell` Object.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Also Do you know anyother way to verify this?

Comment: This table should use a CellFactory to create `TableCall` instances (I guess `CustomComboBoxTableCell` is his successor). If possible, show the factory code and `CustomComboBoxTableCell`

Comment: @mrmcwolf Updated Now!

Comment: Where is the `disable` state of the combobox changed? I can't see anywhere in your code that you set it after the initial construction... I suspect it may be in the `ClumpTableNodeAction`, but it is not included?  
Anyway - you have to remember `TableView` uses virtual nodes, which means it keeps a small number of cells (provided by `CallFactories`), and re-uses them, so a `Cell` constructed for one row may later be used for a different row/value (via calls to `updateItem` and `updateIndex`)

Comment: There is also no mention of the `GROUP_BUTTONS`  in `clumpCellCall`, which is weird - how are the buttons even displayed? From what I see it should be displayed as a `TextTableCell` due to the `default` clause in the switch...

Comment: @sillyfly I've re-updated with the code for `GROUP_BUTTONS` in switch snippet. I'd removed before. 
Also please note `comboBox.disableProperty().bind( data.disableProperty() );` which is binded property for disability.

Comment: @sillyfly What you said is exactly right: "Anyway - you have to remember TableView uses virtual nodes, which means it keeps a small number of cells (provided by CallFactories), and re-uses them, so a Cell constructed for one row may later be used for a different row/value (via calls to updateItem and updateIndex) "

This is what I want to overcome. Because of this some of the cell are reused for other rows, hence odd behaviour. How can I mitigate this?

Comment: I can't quite follow the complete logic, but what you will have to do is un-bind the property and re-bind it upon `updateItem` (or your `renewItem` method).

Comment: @sillyfly Un-Bind /Re-Bind the data property with model or you are talking about `ComboBox` selection change listener? Please suggest me a small snippet of code, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make an attempt to answer, but as I said the code is hard for me to follow (especially as it is partial, so some methods I can only assume the purpose of).

The issue, as stated in the comments, is node virtualization in `TableView`. You can't go around it, and you really don't want to - it is a means to vastly improve performance, as you don't need hundreds or thousands of UI nodes (which are "heavy" and degrade performance), but only enough to fill the displayed portion of the table, thus supporting a much larger dataset.

The problem, as far as I can see, as that you have some property of the *row* (is it currently editable or not) which you need to be reflected in certain *columns*. More specifically, you want the combo box's `disable` property to always reflect the `disable` property of the row it pertains to, so in `updateItem` you will have to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(T, empty); 
    if (empty) {
        setGraphic(null); 
    } else {
        renewItem(item); 
        // since the disable property if given by the row value, not only the column value
        // we need to get the row value. The cast is needed due to a design oversight 
        // in JavaFX 8, which is fixed in newer versions. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144088 
        ConstraintsDataModel data = ((TableRow<ConstraintsDataModel>)getTableRow())
                .getItem();
        combobox.disableProperty().unbind();
        combobox.disableProperty().bind(data.disableProperty()); 
    }
}
```

This is assuming your row data type is indeed `ConstaintDataModel`, I couldn't quite follow through.

Another option which may be more elegant is to use the `editing` property of a row - bind the combo box's `disable` property to the negation of the `editing` property of the row, and use `startEdit` and `cancelEdit`/`commitEdit` when you start and end editing. This way you will not have to re-bind the disable property of the combo box, as it will always refer to the correct row.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this certainly helped me. I understood about table view virtual nodes. I've modified the usage of the answer to fit my API.

Comment: Could you please suggest me, how did you know about virtual nodes while rendering? Any reference or book?

Comment: Virtualization is explained in the documentation of [`Cell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html). I have mostly learned from the documentation, trial and error, and helpful answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: Which one is better using `getTableRow()).getItem()` or using `getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()))`?
As Now I've is data model mismatch with respect to row order. Already set data changes to `null`, when data of something cell changes.

Comment: I think it is mostly a matter of preference, but I prefer `getTableRow`, because them I am certain there is nothing funny going on with indices (is "row index" the same as "item index"? Probably, but I'm not sure!).   If you have another question it is usually best to open a new question. If you think this is part of the same question (that is - my answer doesn't fully solve your question) please edit your original question to clarify.